# Unexpected error: replace() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-3.1

In settings.py I have:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

Then In some view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings


def test_view(request):
    return HttpResponse( settings.BASE_DIR.replace("src", "") )
```

This gives error: `replace() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

It confuses me, how that error appears? also if do:

```
return HttpResponse( settings.BASE_DIR )
```

this returns full path, something like: `/home/full/path/to/project/src`

also this works

```
 return HttpResponse( "/home/full/path/to/project/src".replace("src", "") )
```

Can you help me and tell what is wrong with this line:

```
return HttpResponse( settings.BASE_DIR.replace("src", "") )
```

?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Convert it to `string`:

```
str(settings.BASE_DIR).replace("src", "")
```

Comment: BTW, error message seems bit confusing right? more relevant could be "replace() only works for string data types" or something like?  just saying..

Comment: No, because `replace` actually **does work** for `Path` instances. It's just a different method. For exemple, calling `replace` on an `int` type will raise `AttributeError`.

Comment: Yes, as @Le Minaw wrote, that is the intern  method of `Path` instance.

Comment: Now I see, so there is `str.replace()` and `Path.replace` also. Thank you

Comment: @LeMinaw none of that explains the error message, which is cryptic at best.  The error message is implying that three arguments were supplied when they were not.

Answer (score 5):

You're not calling the `replace` method of the `str` stype, but the one of the `Path` class from `pathlib` (because `BASE_DIR` is a `Path` instance).

It only takes two args (eg. `my_path.replace(target))`, therefore the exception.

[Docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.replace) about what is does (basically renaming a file or directory).

Cast your `Path` instance to a string.

Answer (score 2):

From Django 3.1 BASE_DIR is by default set to new [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module Path object   as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/#miscellaneous)

from  [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/project_template/project_name/settings.py-tpl#L16)

> `BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent`

Coincidentally Path has also [`.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.replace) method but it does not have same use case as string replace

You might want to use instead [`parent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent) accessor:

```
settings.BASE_DIR.parent
```